# set CSS class depending on returned string with Ember

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-controllers

Im still learning ember and i didn't got how i can apply certain CSS class depending on the returned string of a model on a certain controller.

The official documentation (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yoqifiguva/1/edit?html,js,output)  only covers when you have a boolean.

I didn't manage to apply this knowledge for my case.
I have status string string like :  "passed", "failed", "pendent" and "blocked", which i want to apply different css class for each status.

Any examples on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind-attr`, for example:

```
<ul>
{{#each item in model}}
  <li {{bind-attr class='item.status'}}>An item with status: `{{item.status}}`</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Which produces following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="passed" data-bindattr-262="262">An item with status: `passed`</li>
  <li class="failed" data-bindattr-265="265">An item with status: `failed`</li>
</ul>
```

For collection:

```
[
  YourModel.create({ status: 'passed'}),
  YourModel.create({ status: 'failed'})
]
```

of objects declared like:

```
YourModel = Em.Object.extend({
  status: null
});
```

[Demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qetuqiqabo)

You can also create `Component` which can be reused with many models.
Component code:

```
App.StatusItemComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['status'],

  status: function() {
    var modelStatus = this.get('model.status');
    if (modelStatus)
      return 'status-' + modelStatus;
  }.property('model.status')
});
```

Template code:

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{#status-item model=item}}
    An item with status: {{item.status}}
  {{/status-item}}
{{/each}}
```

[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/yovosayiru)

Comment: it certainly resolve my problem but its not scalable.. i mean, if i have stats for other models that i should represent if css class this approach will not work..

Comment: You can create component with `classNameBindings: ['model.status']` instead and reuse that.

Comment: Can you give a light on that?

Comment: Updated answer with `Component` usage example.